# Supremum & Maximum: Infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, probability-limit-theorems

I'm asked to tell what the supremum and maximum is of the following set:
$$\begin{Bmatrix}n:n\in\mathbb{N}\end{Bmatrix}$$

I don't know that I should say $\text{sup}\begin{Bmatrix}n:n\in\mathbb{N}\end{Bmatrix}\overset{?}{=}\infty$ because that seems an abuse, but I'm not sure like I said.

Comment: Is it "is" or "are?"

Comment: Look at the numbers, start listing them. The biggest is $1/2$.  And next you may be asked about min and infimum. No min, infimum $0$.

Comment: Does the definition of the natural numbers you need to work with include 0 or not? If it does, you may be correct about $\infty$, otherwise, you have a strictly sequence, so you have a well-defined supremum which should be the maximal element too.

Comment: No, the author doesn't acknowledge $0$.

Comment: @Avraham: You are wrong. Even if $0$ was taken as part of the natural numbers in this context, the supremum isn't going to be $\infty$. The reason is that $\frac10$ is not infinity; it is simply undefined.

Comment: Who is wrong? Read below...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks. Again, a lack of precision--the unconscious assumption of the reals when we are strictly in the naturals.

Answer (score 4):

Try writing out the first few numbers:

$$\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac 1 6, ...$$

So the supremum and the maximum agree with each other, since there's a largest element, namely $1/2$.

Edit: For clarification, the question originally asked what the supremum and maximum of $\{\frac{1}{2n} : n \in \Bbb{N}\}$ are.

Comment: The OPs seems to be confused about $0\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: What a blunder. Yes, I know. I copied the wrong set in. I meant $\{n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: @LoieBenedicte I see. In that case, again try writing out elements: Note that there are arbitrarily large elements, so the supremum must be infinity.

Comment: It's just that the definition of supremum doesn't seem to allow for $\infty$. I mean what does $n<\infty$ mean?

Comment: @LoieBenedicte What definition of supremum are you using? Normally, it's perfectly allowable to have infinity - the supremum being infinite is entirely equivalent to stating that the set is unbounded.

Comment: See below and above. @T.Bongers said it more precisely than I did <s>If the supremum is infinity it just means that there is no largest finite element</s> The supremum of the set of natural numbers is infinity.

Comment: @Avraham That's not entirely correct - for example, the interval $(0, 1)$ certainly has no largest element, but its supremum is $1$.

Comment: I agree I was not precise enough.

Comment: What about $\text{sup}\{1\}$? Is the $\text{max}$ the same?

Comment: Yes, the supremum and maximum of the set $\{1\}$ are both $1$.

Comment: OK, I appreciate all your help everyone. Thank you. `:-)`

Comment: I ask because I suspect that $\text{sup}\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1}\pmatrix{1-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}}=1$.

Comment: @LoieBenedicte Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @T.Bongers Hmmm... Well what about $\text{sup}\bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1}[\frac{1}{n},2-\frac{1}{n}]$? There are closed brackets, but I think this is $(0,2)$, so the $\text{sup}$ would be $2$, and the $\text{max}$ would be . . . nonexistent?

Answer (score 3):

As I and others mentioned in the comments, if the author does not have 0 in his or her definition of the natural numbers, you have a strictly decreasing sequence of rational numbers with a well-defined maximal element and supremum at 1/2. You have no well defined minimal element, but you have an infimum at 0.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of supremum and maximum come only for a bounded set. You are considering the set $\{n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} = \{1, 2, 3, \dots\}$. This is an unbounded set in $\mathbb{R}$, as for any positive real number $G$, you shall get an element $m \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $m > G$.

So Supremum of the set does not exists, and same for maximum.